# Rendering Placeholder Items on React Components While Loading from Server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, mern

I am working on a MERN application where people can add user created content. I have incorporated a basic loading functionality to give the user feedback when fetching data from the server. However I am hoping for some improvements for better performance and reducing loading times.

My current approach:

As an example I will explain my PostComponent which will request user created posts from the database through a dispatched redux action (getPosts). The posts are rendered in a child component PostFeed and subsequently mapped into individual PostItem components.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PostForm from './PostForm';
import PostFeed from './PostFeed';
import Spinner from '../common/Spinner';
import { getPosts } from '../../actions/postActions';

class Posts extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getPosts();
  }

  render() {
    const { posts, loading } = this.props.post;
    let postContent;

    if (posts === null || loading) {
      postContent = <Spinner />;
    } else {
      postContent = <PostFeed posts={posts} />;
    }

    return (
      <div className="feed">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">
              <PostForm />
              {postContent}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Posts.propTypes = {
  getPosts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  post: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  post: state.post,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPosts })(Posts);
```

Before the posts are loaded, I am setting a boolean loading to `true`. After getting all the posts, loading is set to `false` again. The `if` statement in the component above is rendering a spinner which is a .gif file or the PostFeed component depending on the state of the loading boolean.

postActions:

```
...
export const setPostLoading = () => {
  return {
    type: POST_LOADING,
  };
};

export const getPosts = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(setPostLoading());
  axios
    .get('/api/posts')
    .then(res => dispatch({
      type: GET_POSTS,
      payload: res.data,
    }))
    .catch(err => dispatch({
      type: GET_POSTS,
      payload: null,
    }));
};
...
```

postReducer:

```
...
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case POST_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    case GET_POSTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: action.payload,
        loading: false,
      };
...
```

This all works fine this way but I have two concerns about this method:

First, using spinners while loading components makes things jump around on the page a bit. While not necessarily a bad thing, I like to create the most seamless user experience and find implementing placeholders a more elegant solution.

[Placeholder Loading Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJLzZ.png)

How do I achieve implementing placeholder items for each separate component so content does not jump around and stays nicely postioned while loading?

Second, When loading the posts, it is loading all available posts that are stored in the database. I can imagine when having excessive amounts of posts, loading all the individual PostItems might take too long and take a lot of unnecessary bandwidth.

How could I add the functionality to only load the content displayed in the browser window so more are loaded when the user scrolls down? Probably by scroll eventhandler? But how does it decide which PostItem to render and which to keep as placeholders?

Hope I explained it clear enough, still relatively new to react/redux so there could some mistakes here. Any tips, suggestions or best practices are welcome.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You are asking a number of questions here. First, it sounds like you've come to grips with needing your "skeleton" to display for each component, and the good news is there are several solutions available such as [react-content-loader](https://github.com/danilowoz/react-content-loader) which uses customizable SVG, [react-placeholder](https://github.com/buildo/react-placeholder), (or you can roll your own using [react-transition-group](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group). The documentation will explain how you manage the transition per component as you requested.

With respect to the "excessive amount" of items coming back from your axios API call, it's hard to say without a knowing a rough number (100s, 1000s, more, etc.) and if you've found a performance issue with how much data you're returning. If the number ends up being problematic, what you are looking for is called "virtual (or infinite) scrolling" and pagination where you're not requesting ALL of the data at once, but rather in chunks. For example, StackOverflow uses paging, the new Reddit uses infinite scroll. Again, there are NPM packages for that too such as [react-tiny-virtual-list](https://github.com/clauderic/react-tiny-virtual-list).